# How do I allow Google to index login-required parts of my site?

Tags: seo, web-crawler

It seems like Google can index certain sites or forums (I can't name any offhand as its been months since I last saw one) and when accessing you are prompted with a request to register or login.

How would I make my site open for Google to index and have a regular login for others?

Comment: Are you talking about the main Google Internet Search at http://www.google.com or are you talking about Google Mini or the Google search appliance? The answer is different depending on which of these you mean.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Google supports the concept of [flexible sampling](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7532484) where you can show a limited amount of content to users from Google search results while allowing Googlebot to crawl all of it.

Google allows you to either show users a limited number of articles  (**metering**) or show a portion of each article (**lead-in**).

From a technical standpoint you need to:

- Allow Googlebot to access all your content by user agent or by validating Googlebot's IP addresses.
- Mark up your pages with structured data that indicates that they have paywall content.
- Implement showing limited amounts of content to users who come to your site from Google.

This is a replacement for Google's older "First Click Free" policy under which you had to show a full page of content every time somebody clicked to your site from a Google search result.

Comment: That actually explains a lot, for me. I still remember my first visit to Quora, by way of Google, which really ticked me off since I thought it was being indecisive. I think it's worth noting that it's easy to abuse by way of just copying a link and plugging it back in to Google. I suppose most probably wont, but still, something to consider if you're thinking of using First Click Free.

Comment: fwiw, this article now [tries to] link to a blog post deprecating the First Click Free policy: [Enabling more high quality content](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/10/enabling-more-high-quality-content.html)

Comment: @patridge  I updated this answer with details from Google's new policy

Comment: "Implement showing limited amounts of content to users who come to your site from Google." How to do for users not coming from google? Just show a login page? This is not cloaking? Form user's perspective, it is the same as cloaking.

Comment: @William The kind of cloaking that you can be penalized for is showing different content to Googlebot and Google users.   Google doesn't care how you treat users.  You could just show a login page and not risk a penalty from Google.  Assuming that you are trying to optimize for the most subscriptions, you are free to use any techniques with non-Google users and are not limited to metering and lead-in.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Do you mean if I serve a login page for people coming from google while serve real content for googlebot, it is considered as cloaking and may be penalized. But if I serve login page for people NOT coming from google while serve real content for googlebot, that will be okay? This does not sound reasonable. If so, I could easily serve real content according to the (google) referrer and avoid being penalized.

Comment: That's how sites like the New York times used to do it. Serving real content to users referred from Google and to googlebot makes Google happy, even if other users can't see the content. The New York times changed the way their site works because people figured they could just search for an article on Google to see it for free. Now they work using the flexible sampling policy of Google where they show all the content to Googlebot but limit all users to some number free articles or show a lead in.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I just wonder how google differentiates cloaking from flexible sampling. If website owners only need to add a structured data to tell google "I'm blocking users but I'm telling you I'm doing this so don't consider it as cloaking and penalize me", that is ridiculous.

Comment: Why is that ridiculous?   If Google didn't have such a policy some high quality content archives would choose not to be indexed rather than have to give away their content for free.    Google is trying to make things searchable, provide searchers with a small amount of free content or at least a content preview, and allow content providers to run a content business.   You should read about the history of this policy.  The flexible sampling policy replaced the "first click free" policy: https://searchengineland.com/google-first-click-free-replaced-flexible-sampling-283667

Comment: It would be hard to do a lot of malicious cloaking and disguise it with flexible sampling.  The content you show to Googlebot still has to match the free samples and the paid content.   Providing flexible sampling structured data wouldn't provide cover for sneaky redirects or irrelevant keyword stuffing.

Answer (score 8):

This is frowned upon.

1. Your page rank suffers if Google sees this (google "expert exchange google").
2. People can still access your site with Google Cache
3. You have to take into account every other search engine too, as you'll have to use "browser sniffing"

What you'd do is sniff for the [`Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)`  and `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)` user-agents](http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/internet/google/googlebot-spoofer/) (at least), and deliver to that client different content altogether.

Another option, is to do what [expersexchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/) does, and have all the information buried deep down on the page. That way you have your cake, and eat it too: users don't *completely* hate you, your page rank doesn't suffer, and you still <del>discriminate non-registered users</del> give a better experience to registered users.

Comment: at one point I remember that site blocked the real answers on IE, but not firefox

Comment: is this still true in 2019? quoting [Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/paywalled-content): "If you want Google to crawl and index your entire page, including the paywalled sections, make sure Googlebot, and Googlebot-News if applicable, can access your page" - it sounds like this is now normal and encouraged by Google?

Comment: "2. People can still access your site with Google Cache" - Any _paywalled_ content should be served with a `noarchive` robots meta tag (or `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header) to prevent the "cache link" being returned in the search results.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are asking?

**Can Google Site Search index my password-protected pages?**

If so then [here is the answer from Google](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72365)

> Google Site Search is only able to
>   provide search results for pages that
>   are publicly available for crawl, not
>   websites that require password
>   information. If you have protected web
>   content such as intranet pages that
>   you need to index and search, you
>   might want to consider one of Google's
>   universal search options. You can
>   learn more about the Google Mini and
>   Google Search Appliance [here](http://www.google.com/enterprise/intranet_search.html).

Answer (score 3):

We open a backdoor for Google and other search engines.

We have a white-list of IPs used by major search engines. If we see the requests are from one of the IPs, we bypass authentication and display an abbreviated version of the page so Google can index it but not all information are available from Google's cache.

We tried to use `User-Agent` but found people abuse it. IP is much harder to hack.

Comment: Wont this be considered cloaking ? Since the user will see something different (login screen) and the search engine is seeing something different (abbreviated content) ? Or do you also show the abbreviated content to users, if they are coming from google ?

Comment: Could you share your list?

Comment: This could be considered _cloaking_ unless users see the same content - but that doesn't sound as if it's the case here. However, Google allows you to provide structured data to indicate the paywalled content and avoid the cloaking issue. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/paywalled-content @RaviGidwani

Answer (score 0):

Create sitemap for Google Indexing and upload it into Google.Please visit this link : [Inside Google Sitemaps: Using Sitemap Index Files](http://sitemaps.blogspot.com/2005/08/using-sitemap-index-files.html)